# arcpy.setValue for Condition from Dictionary

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy

I am trying to create a function to update multiple fields based on different criteria. I want to pass the field name and condition through a dictionary (please see the function description in the enclosed code).

```
def CalculateFieldsBasedOnCondition(sourceTable, fieldNames_Condition):
  '''
  fieldNames_Condition = {'TestID': '"LOC-"+(row.getValue("OBJECTID"))',
                          'UPADATED':'Yes'} 

  usage: CalculateFieldsBasedOnCondition(sourceTable, fieldNames_Condition)
  '''
  try:
    rows=arcpy.UpdateCursor(sourceTable)
    for row in rows:
      for fieldName, condition in fieldNames_Condition.iteritems():
        row.setValue(fieldName,condition)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    del row, rows

  except Exception, e:
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

I am working with Python 2.6.5, Arcpy 10 and Win 7 64 and the sourceTable is a FileGDB Featureclass.

I would like to get the result of TestID field as "LOC-101" where 101 is the value of the ObjectID field. If I run this now-it'll write the condition as such as it's treated as a string. How can I parse the condition as a non string item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string that contains Python code you want to run, you can use the Python Built-In Function `exec`.

In your case what you could do is:

```
def CalculateFieldsBasedOnCondition(sourceTable, fieldNames_Condition):
'''
fieldNames_Condition = {'TestID': 'id = "LOC-" + str(row.getValue("OBJECTID"))',
                        'UPADATED':'Yes'} 

usage: CalculateFieldsBasedOnCondition(sourceTable, fieldNames_Condition)
'''
try:
  rows=arcpy.UpdateCursor(sourceTable)
  for row in rows:
    for fieldName, condition in fieldNames_Condition.iteritems():
      exec(condition)
      row.setValue(fieldName,id)
      rows.updateRow(row)
  del row, rows

except Exception, e:
  import traceback, sys
  tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
  print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
  print e.message
```

This should execute the `row.getValue` code in your `condition` and return a new variable `id`.  Then, you can use `id` in your `row.setValue`.

Here is a simpler example of `exec`:

```
x = 'y = "LOC" + str(2*5)'
exec(x)
print y # should return "LOC10"
```